# RxJava2 + OkHttp Undeliverable exception: Socket Timeout

Tags: java, retrofit, rx-java2, okhttp

I am seeing the following crash on Crashlytics:

```
Fatal Exception: io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
       at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:366)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.disposeAll(FlowableFlatMap.java:590)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.cancel(FlowableFlatMap.java:354)
       at io.reactivex.internal.subscriptions.SubscriptionHelper.cancel(SubscriptionHelper.java:189)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.cancel(FlowableSubscribeOn.java:141)
       at io.reactivex.internal.subscriptions.SubscriptionHelper.cancel(SubscriptionHelper.java:189)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableCombineLatest$CombineLatestInnerSubscriber.cancel(FlowableCombineLatest.java:540)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableCombineLatest$CombineLatestCoordinator.cancelAll(FlowableCombineLatest.java:454)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableCombineLatest$CombineLatestCoordinator.cancel(FlowableCombineLatest.java:209)
       at io.reactivex.internal.subscriptions.SubscriptionHelper.cancel(SubscriptionHelper.java:189)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$InnerSubscriber.dispose(FlowableFlatMap.java:690)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.innerError(FlowableFlatMap.java:602)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$InnerSubscriber.onError(FlowableFlatMap.java:668)
       at io.reactivex.internal.subscribers.BasicFuseableSubscriber.onError(BasicFuseableSubscriber.java:101)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.onError(FlowableSubscribeOn.java:102)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.checkTerminate(FlowableFlatMap.java:566)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.drainLoop(FlowableFlatMap.java:374)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.drain(FlowableFlatMap.java:366)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.innerError(FlowableFlatMap.java:605)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$InnerSubscriber.onError(FlowableFlatMap.java:668)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleToFlowable$SingleToFlowableObserver.onError(SingleToFlowable.java:68)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableElementAtSingle$ElementAtObserver.onError(ObservableElementAtSingle.java:104)
       at io.reactivex.internal.util.HalfSerializer.onError(HalfSerializer.java:133)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableRetryWhen$RepeatWhenObserver.innerError(ObservableRetryWhen.java:132)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableRetryWhen$RepeatWhenObserver$InnerRepeatObserver.onError(ObservableRetryWhen.java:172)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.checkTerminate(ObservableFlatMap.java:495)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.drainLoop(ObservableFlatMap.java:331)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.drain(ObservableFlatMap.java:323)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$InnerObserver.onError(ObservableFlatMap.java:571)
       at io.reactivex.internal.disposables.EmptyDisposable.error(EmptyDisposable.java:63)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableError.subscribeActual(ObservableError.java:37)
       at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:11194)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.subscribeInner(ObservableFlatMap.java:162)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.onNext(ObservableFlatMap.java:139)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableZip$ZipCoordinator.drain(ObservableZip.java:205)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableZip$ZipObserver.onNext(ObservableZip.java:276)
       at io.reactivex.subjects.PublishSubject$PublishDisposable.onNext(PublishSubject.java:309)
       at io.reactivex.subjects.PublishSubject.onNext(PublishSubject.java:230)
       at io.reactivex.subjects.SerializedSubject.onNext(SerializedSubject.java:104)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableRetryWhen$RepeatWhenObserver.onError(ObservableRetryWhen.java:106)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleToObservable$SingleToObservableObserver.onError(SingleToObservable.java:65)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleDoOnSuccess$DoOnSuccess.onError(SingleDoOnSuccess.java:64)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleMap$MapSingleObserver.onError(SingleMap.java:69)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSingleSingle$SingleElementObserver.onError(ObservableSingleSingle.java:95)
       at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable$BodyObserver.onError(BodyObservable.java:72)
       at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:56)
       at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:11194)
       at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)
       at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:11194)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSingleSingle.subscribeActual(ObservableSingleSingle.java:35)
       at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3096)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleMap.subscribeActual(SingleMap.java:34)
       at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3096)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleDoOnSuccess.subscribeActual(SingleDoOnSuccess.java:35)
       at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3096)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleToObservable.subscribeActual(SingleToObservable.java:34)
       at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:11194)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableRetryWhen$RepeatWhenObserver.subscribeNext(ObservableRetryWhen.java:150)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableRetryWhen.subscribeActual(ObservableRetryWhen.java:60)
       at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:11194)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableElementAtSingle.subscribeActual(ObservableElementAtSingle.java:37)
       at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3096)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleToFlowable.subscribeActual(SingleToFlowable.java:37)
       at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:13234)
       at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:13180)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.onNext(FlowableFlatMap.java:163)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromArray$ArraySubscription.slowPath(FlowableFromArray.java:164)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromArray$BaseArraySubscription.request(FlowableFromArray.java:89)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.onSubscribe(FlowableFlatMap.java:117)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromArray.subscribeActual(FlowableFromArray.java:37)
       at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:13234)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap.subscribeActual(FlowableFlatMap.java:53)
       at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:13234)
       at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:13180)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.run(FlowableSubscribeOn.java:82)
       at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
       at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Now according to [the official documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/docs/What's-different-in-2.0.md#error-handling) this is because somewhere in some rx chain the exception cannot be delivered and thus rather than hiding it Rx handles it by causing a crash.

I know I could just avoid this behavior by using

```
RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler(e -> { });
```

but I'd rather find the source of the problem. However nowhere in the exception log can I see the actual api request or method call that is causing this, only the stack trace from Rx and Okhttp/retrofit.

My app is quite big so I'd have to go through all my repositories to see where I might have missed an `onError` handling.

Is there a better way to debug this issue?

Comment: We had a similar issue. Network calls were taking too long, the users would send our app to the background, forcing us to dispose. When the socket timeout happened we add no one to process the error and saw the above exception. We ended up changing the global error handler to ignore socket timeouts. If you want I can provide an example.

Comment: @Fred that would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the question comments, I had to deal with a similar issue. Our problem was in our Android app. The network calls would take too long and the users would send the app to the background. When this happens, we dispose of the subscriptions. When the socket timeout happens there's no one listening for the exception and this causes an `UndeliverableException`.

We've replaced the default error handler with (it's in kotlin, I hope this is ok):

```
private object DefaultErrorHandler : Consumer<Throwable> {
  override fun accept(t: Throwable) {
    when (t) {
        is UndeliverableException -> accept(t.cause!!)
        is NullPointerException,
        is IllegalArgumentException -> Thread.currentThread().run {
            uncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(this, t)
        }
        else -> // Swallow the exception here. We logged it to Crashlytics...
    }
  }
}

val defaultErrorHandler: Consumer<Throwable> = DefaultErrorHandler

// Then on application start we would replace the error handler
RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler(defaultErrorHandler)
```

*I'm pretty sure `defaultErrorHandler` is a horrible name. Sorry about that.*

A bit of explanation. The exceptions we don't swallow are `NullPointerException` and `IllegalArgumentException`. These get forwarded to the current thread's uncaught exceptions handler. We did this because these are usually related to programming errors.

We check for `UndeliverableExceptions` and unwrap them to rerun again through the same consumer. This is just to make sure we run the correct logic on the exception that couldn't be delivered.

All other exceptions are swallowed and logged into crashlytics for further assessment.

One key thing, this works for our use cases. It might be that you need to adapt it to yours. I'm not saying this is the best way to do it. It's an example. Perhaps for you, you want to just ignore socket timeouts.

Comment: your explanation sounds like my issue as well. thanks

Comment: About this line `else -> // Swallow the exception here. We logged it to Crashlytics...`, should we really do anything here you mean? or it'd redirect the exception automatically to the producer?

Comment: For `accept(t.cause!!)` is it possible to with this approach we get stuck in a loop?

Comment: `accept(t.cause!!)` never actually got us in a loop. I must confess I don't know of any case where the exception causes circle back to an old one in the stack trace.

Comment: @Dr.jacky yes you should definitely do something there. It won't do any redirection as far as I know.

Comment: For `UnknownHostException` I'm handling them on the top level codes and returning a custom `Failure` and showing related toast, but in any case that I got into `IOException || SocketException`, how can I achieve the same logic? Showing a network problem toast, for example. Is this enough: `uncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(this, t as Failure.NoInternet)`

Comment: oh, this piece of code is most likely going to be run when your app has no control of the ui. At least it's intended for that. The only case where you would reach this handler is when you've disposed of your streams and won't handle any more events.

Comment: @Fred Yea, I know that. I've solved it with a PublishShubject and listen to that emit on my Activity and showing the relative Dialog.

Comment: this answer provides a lot but also wanted to link this which has some more information https://proandroiddev.com/rxjava2-undeliverableexception-f01d19d18048